# What specific Apache modules come bundled in MAMP/MAMP Pro 3? (mod_deflate?)

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I am trying to figure out which Apache modules come with with MAMP.  The marketing website

http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/

somewhere just says something like "over 70 modules" and there is a screenshot of the incomplete list.  I can't find in the the User Manual either. Specifically, I would like to know if it comes with mod_deflate (on OSX).

If you own a copy on MAMP PRO 3 on OSX, I believe you can figure this out by doing an

```
ls /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules
```

I didn't want to download and install it yet b/c I'm worried it may mess with my current MAMP install, and I'm also not sure if the free MAMP comes with the same modules as MAMP PRO.  If I can figure this out, I can probably convince my boss to upgrade our production server :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out a co-worker has a machine I could install it on.  Here is the output if anyone is curious (no mod_deflate)

```
httpd.exp
mod_actions.so
mod_alias.so
mod_asis.so
mod_auth_basic.so
mod_auth_digest.so
mod_authn_anon.so
mod_authn_dbd.so
mod_authn_dbm.so
mod_authn_default.so
mod_authn_file.so
mod_authz_dbm.so
mod_authz_default.so
mod_authz_groupfile.so
mod_authz_host.so
mod_authz_owner.so
mod_authz_user.so
mod_autoindex.so
mod_bucketeer.so
mod_cache.so
mod_case_filter.so
mod_case_filter_in.so
mod_cern_meta.so
mod_cgi.so
mod_cgid.so
mod_charset_lite.so
mod_dav.so
mod_dav_fs.so
mod_dbd.so
mod_deflate.so
mod_dir.so
mod_disk_cache.so
mod_dumpio.so
mod_echo.so
mod_env.so
mod_example.so
mod_expires.so
mod_ext_filter.so
mod_fastcgi.so
mod_file_cache.so
mod_filter.so
mod_headers.so
mod_ident.so
mod_imagemap.so
mod_include.so
mod_info.so
mod_log_config.so
mod_logio.so
mod_mem_cache.so
mod_mime.so
mod_mime_magic.so
mod_negotiation.so
mod_perl.so
mod_proxy.so
mod_proxy_ajp.so
mod_proxy_balancer.so
mod_proxy_connect.so
mod_proxy_ftp.so
mod_proxy_http.so
mod_proxy_scgi.so
mod_python.so
mod_reqtimeout.so
mod_rewrite.so
mod_setenvif.so
mod_speling.so
mod_ssl.so
mod_status.so
mod_substitute.so
mod_unique_id.so
mod_userdir.so
mod_usertrack.so
mod_version.so
mod_vhost_alias.so
mod_wsgi.so
```